# getting a "Could not load source: 6" console message when calling "pushViewController"??? (code attached)

Tags: iphone, ios, uinavigationcontroller, ekeventkit, ekevent

Any ideas why I would be seeing a "Could not load source: 6" console message when calling "pushViewController"?  The new view seems to come up ok.  The code is:

Code Except:

```
EKEventViewController *eventViewController = [[EKEventViewController alloc] init];
eventViewController.event = event;
eventViewController.allowsEditing = YES;
eventViewController.delegate = self;

[self.navigationController pushViewController:eventViewController animated:YES];  // <== OCCURS HERE
```

Comment: Did you check the IBOutlet connected to the navigationController?

Comment: @Sahil - what do you mean/what are you getting at here?  I don't really understand.  I don't have an IBOutlet specifically specified in my AppDelegate or RootViewController, but the NavController seems to work OK, excepting this case I'm highlighting when I'm at layer 3 of my navController about to push a 4th view...

Comment: Can you check if after pushViewController, does it hit the viewDidLoad of eventViewController (by adding a break point)? Also in the subject line you've mentioned **(code attached)**. What do you mean by this.

Comment: can't put a breakpoint in this controller (which is a EKEventViewController) as this isn't my code (i.e. it's Apple's).  code attached was just referring to the Code Except I had in the question

Comment: sample from developer.apple.com http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/SimpleEKDemo/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40010160
i think it's ok

Comment: but i've got next problem :) http://goo.gl/8fGlJ

Comment: Add .xib file with EKEventViewController in initWithNibName and check both class is UIViewController.

Answer (score 1):

`EKEventViewController` has an IB file which gets loaded? Maybe you're using an image inside your IB/nib file which is no longer in your project. Additionally go to menu "Products" and click on "Clean Build Folder…" (or cmd-option-shift-K)

Comment: EKEventViewController is an Apple controller (#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>) so it's not my code in this case.  I tried the clean build folder but no luck...

Comment: tried setting `eventViewController.delegate = self;` after pushing the controller?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you try to set the frame of this view controller before pushing it.

```
eventViewController.view.frame = CGRectMake(…);

[self.navigationController pushViewController:eventViewController animated:YES];
```

Answer (score 1):

This seems to be new since iOS 5.0. I can verify, that under iOS 4.3 this message does not appear.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a really old question, but (this just happened to me) maybe this will be of use to someone.

Assuming you were trying to test your app on the simulator:

Could not load source: 6 - Some features are not available on the simulator, and you have to run the app on a real device. It simply means that it cannot find the content related to (in your case) the Calendar app.

Comment: Don't know why this was down voted. I got this error message on the simulator; I ran the same app on a device and didn't get the error message. So this seems to me to be a good answer!